# Как на html страницы сделать "карту" и мини-карту

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вообщем есть html страница.
У нее задний фон это некое изображение. Видел на сайтах бывает, нажимаешь на картинку, она открывается в увеличенном виде и ты по ней ездишь курсором. А слева в верхнем углу висит полное изображение в увеличенном формате, и в нем отображается положение на картинке.

В html/css только базовые знания. С js не работал , но как говорится все гуглится.
Можете подсказать куда пытаться копать?

Условное изображение чего хочу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За вас никто не будет писать код, оформите вопрос подобающе с кодом и опишите проблему где у вас, что-то не получается и ошибки если таковы имеются. Если хотите, чтобы за вас написали, вам на фриланс.

Comment: Копайте по слову `magnifier`

Comment: @And - " Можете подсказать куда пытаться копать?". В каком месте я говорю что хочу чтобы за меня писали код? Я спросил куда смотреть.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, спасибо. Это лупа, тут немножко обратное - картинка уже как бы увеличена, в левой миникартинке я хочу отслеживать мое место положенин

Comment: Вы в прямом смысле слова говорите как это реализовать, а значит уже просите реализацию. Не давая ничего в замен, вы ничего не получите в итоге.